# How Can I use Java Stream To Build a List<Integer> And The Integer Between a and b

Tags: java, java-stream

Say I have two variables : `a = 5`, `b = 8`,

And I want :

```
Arrays.asList(5, 6, 7, 8)
```

How Can I Use Java stream To get this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried? Where have you looked? What did you find? In what way was it insufficient? Please don’t give the impression that you just want somebody else to do your work for you.

Answer (score 9):

you can use [IntStream.rangeClosed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#rangeClosed-int-int-) to generate the numbers and collect into a list.

```
List<Integer> result = IntStream.rangeClosed(a, b)
                                .boxed()
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```